# Getting a `500 Unknown Command` when invoking `GET` in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

Alright, so I'm given a `Java` FtpClient class that I am supposed to finish/modify so that the finished product will serve as a WebServer.

The following is a method that lets me interact with the server through command lines.

> ```
> /*
>  * Send ftp command 
>  * @param command: the full command line to send to the ftp server
>  * @param expected_code: the expected response code from the ftp server
>  * @return the response line from the ftp server after sending the command
>  */
> private String sendCommand(String command, int expected_response_code){
>     String response = "";
>     try {
>         // send command to the ftp server
>         controlWriter.writeBytes(command);
>
>         // get response from ftp server
>         response = controlReader.readLine();
>         if (DEBUG) {
>             System.out.println("Current FTP response: " + response);
>         }
>
>         // check validity of response
>         if (!response.startsWith(String.valueOf(expected_response_code)))
>         {
>             throw new IOException(
>                     "Bad response: " + response);
>         }
>     } catch (IOException ex) {
>         System.out.println("IOException: " + ex);
>     }
>     return response;
> }
> ```

However, when I invoke the `GET` command, i.e.

`sendCommand("get " + __file__name__ + "\r\l", 200);`),

I get the following response:

> 500 Unknown command.

I am almost 100% sure this issue has nothing to do with the method I've posted above, but I only posted it so you'll know what I am referring to by the `sendCommand` method).

Has anyone had a similar issue with this command before? If so, how did you work around it?

Comment: "\r\l" looks a bit odd to me. Is that supposed to be carriage return and linefeed? "\r\n"?

Comment: if you are connecting to a microsft ftpserver it means `Invalid port` http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281193

Comment: `getCommand` is actually `sendCommand`?

Comment: not sure what the "\r\n" are supposed to do, but I am told they have to go at the end of every command

Comment: @user2310289 
i am using the `vsftpd` package on Linux

Comment: @D. Kasipovic, my bad. corrected :-)

Comment: btw, the method has been tested with other commands and it seems to work flawlessly with everything (at least every command I've tried) but GET. this is why i am almost 100% sure nothing is wrong with the method i posted

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the server with a plain old command line client and invoke the same GET command syntax ?

Comment: @BrianLindsey "\r\n" is the carriage return and linefeed character. I don't know sendCommand() but since you say it must end of "\r\l" then it should be fine. It was just a question from myself what is "\r\l" just because I've not seen it before.

Comment: Yes I have. I've fired up the server itself through command line and tested the command. works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a very similar side project to the one you're doing here, and I've encountered the same problem you've discussed here. I still haven't figured out why I wasn't able to simly invoke `GET` and read off the data stream, but here's my get-around.

First, you'll need to use `RETR` instead of `GET`. If you're not familiar with what `RETR` does, it basically lets you send a file as a packet of bytes through a temporary `port` you'll generate for data transmission.

To instantiate a temporary `port`, you will need to be im `Passive Mode.` So, type in:

> quote pasv

Your output would look something like the following:

> 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,143,155).

A quick glance at the numbers shown between the two parentheses will probably not mean anything to you, however, two details can be derived from there.

The first 3 numbers represent your `localhost` which is always `127.0.0.1`, an the other two are referred to `p1` and `p2`. In this case, we have `p1 = 143` and `p2 = 155`. These two numbers can be used to figure out which `port` has been assigned to us for data transfer.

Fire up your `command line` interface

To find out the port number, plug in the numbers in the following formula:

> PORT = p1 * 256 + p2

So, our port number in this case is `(143 * 256) + 155` ==> `(36763).`

Now that we have a transfer `port` open for us and ready for data transfer, you can go ahead and instantiate a new `Socket` with the `port number` derived from the formula mentioned above (please note that the numbers will be different every time you run the `quote pasv`, so don't assume these are constants).

The next step here is to send the file from yourself to the client. Note that you're not directing the data packet to a specific client, rather, any client that's currently connected will be receiving the packets.

To send the file, type in the following command:

> quote retr

now you can use the `DataInputStream` class from your `Socket` to read all the bytes, display them, then them into an identical copy of the original file, or do whatever you're planning to do with them.

`Note.. Note... Note... : the commands listed above were meant to be entered from the command line` But since you want your application to handle all the job (I assume), the same commands can be passed from your Java application with a little bit of tweaking around. You will basically only need to take the word `quote` out of all the commands we've used them in.

I think I've typed enough tonight. I am headed to bed now. Let me know if you need further help in a comment below and I will try to respond as soon as possible. Also, let me know if anything I have said is not making sense to you.